# SBT-java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

sbt compile gives Success
sbt run gives the error mentioned above.

My Directory Structure is a little bit different from the regular SBT structure:

[Directory structure that I need... Build.sbt inside main project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AscQS.png)

[Build.sbt inside SubProject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCIlj.png)

**MainClass.scala**

```
object MainClass extends App {
   println("Hello world!")
}
```

Note: Things I have already tried in Build.sbt of main project:

```
 1. scalaSource in (Compile, run) := baseDirectory.value / "App" / "js"  
 2. mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("MainClass")
 3. mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("App/js/src/main/scala/MainClass")
```

I am not able to figure out the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to declare additional `project`s in `.sbt` files that are in subdirectories. All projects have to be declared in `.sbt` files at the root of build.

This means that your `AppJs` and `AppJvm` never get to have any effect, and those projects do not actually exist in your build.

You'll have to declare `AppJs`, `AppJvm`, and any other `project` you need in the top-level `build.sbt` file.